# How to make a polygon following terrain using CesiumJS

Tags: polygon, cesiumjs

As far as I understand it, Cesium can draw polygons ( boxes ) floating above terrain by specifying height and extrudedHeight attributes of PolygonGeometry object. The polygon can be clamped to ground using GroundPrimitive object. I need a combination of both - a polygon, which has bottom side floating above ground, but it follows its height - let's say the polygon's bottom side is always 1000m above ground. Its top side can follow the terrain as well or it can be flat. Is there a way, how to achieve this using Cesium?